# JButton on top of Animated Timed paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, jcomponent

I have a BVH player that has 9 views that work on a timer to animate them and I'm trying to place controls on top of each panel to control transform operations individually.
The buttons are being rendered behind my paintComponent but can be clicked sometimes. I also have a MouseListener to adjust the transform of the skeleton and sometimes it works. I can post the listener, but I don't think it is important.

I've tried various combinations of graphics.dispose and graphics2d.dispose and I've tried changing the position of super.paintComponent(g) with weird results but nothing good.
Below is a video showing the problem. If you watch closely you'll see the buttons popping up when you hover over where they are supposed to be. You'll also see that when I g.dispose() it gets stranger with the buttons in two places but only clicking in one place (which is not where they are most visible).
https://youtu.be/CyFpUlbFI1U
Here is my source code:

```
public SkeletonPlayer(int camera, double scale, int rotLeftRight, int rotUpDown, double translateLeftRight, double translateUpDown) {
    this.camera = camera;
    this.scale = scale;
    this.rotLeftRight = rotLeftRight;
    this.rotUpDown = rotUpDown;
    this.translateLeftRight = translateLeftRight;
    this.translateUpDown = translateUpDown;
    panel = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);

            AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(0, 0);
            at.rotate(Math.toRadians(90), Math.toRadians(90), Math.toRadians(90));

            for (int n = 0; n < MainFrame.skeleton[camera].getNodes().size(); n++) {
                Node node = MainFrame.skeleton[camera].getNodes().get(n);
                int x1 = (int) (scale * node.getPosition().getX());
                int y1 = (int) (-scale * node.getPosition().getY());
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.fillOval((int) (x1 - 2), (int) (y1 - 2), 4, 4);

                g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                //g2d.drawString(node.getName(), x1 + 10, y1);

                for (Node child : node.getChildrens()) {
                    int x2 = (int) (scale * child.getPosition().getX());
                    int y2 = (int) (-scale * child.getPosition().getY());
                    g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
                }
            }

            int x1 = (int) (scale * groundPlane.rootNode.getPosition().getX());
            int y1 = (int) (-scale * groundPlane.rootNode.getPosition().getY());
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.fillOval((int) (x1 - 2), (int) (y1 - 2), 4, 4);

            for (int n = 1; n < groundPlane.nodes.size(); n++) {
                Node node = groundPlane.nodes.get(n);

                int x2 = (int) (scale * node.getPosition().getX());
                int y2 = (int) (-scale * node.getPosition().getY());
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2d.fillOval((int) (x2 - 2), (int) (y2 - 2), 4, 4);

                g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);

                g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
                //System.out.println("line:" + x1 + "," + y1 + " " + x2 + "," + y2);
            }
        }
    };
    panel.addMouseListener(this);
    panel.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    panel.addMouseWheelListener(this);
    MigLayout layout = new MigLayout(
            "insets 10, gap 10, wrap", // Layout Constraints
            "[fill,grow][fill,grow][fill,grow]", // Column constraints with default align
            "[fill,grow][fill,grow][fill,grow]");
    panel.setLayout(layout);
    panel.add(new JButton("here"));
    panel.add(new JButton("here"));
    panel.add(new JButton("here"));
    panel.add(new JButton("here"));
    panel.add(new JButton("here"));
    panel.add(new JButton("here"));
    panel.add(new JButton("here"));
    panel.add(new JButton("here"));
    panel.add(new JButton("here"));
}
```

And here is the timer:

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            update();
        }
    }, 0, (long) Math.round(motion.getFrameTime() * 1000));

private static void update() {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SKELETON_PLAYERS; i++) {
        MainFrame.skeleton[i].setPose((int) frameIndex, i);
        skeletonPlayers[i].groundPlane.setPose(i);
        skeletonPlayers[i].panel.repaint();
    }
    //skeleton.setPose(null);
    frameIndex += 1;
    if (frameIndex > motion.getFrameSize() - 1) {
        frameIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, Swing is not thread safe, so you shouldn't be updating it from outside the Event Dispatching Thread. Second, you're screen with the transformation of the `Graphics` context (translate and rotate), because `Graphics` is a shared context, any changes you make to it will affect any other components painted afterwards.  Better to use `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();` (and then `g2d.dispose()` when you're done)

Comment: I do use Graphics2D... please refer to the posted code. I don't know what you mean by updating outside the dispatching thread, are you referring to the Timer? Is there some other triggering mechanism I should be using to time drawing frames?

Comment: *"I do use Graphics2D... please refer to the posted code"* BUT, as I said, you are changing the state of the context which is then been used to paint all the other components after, with the same transformations applied, this is going to screw up how the other components are rendered, this is why I suggested to use `Graphics#create` to make a "copy" the state information, so you don't screw up the original. *"Is there some other triggering mechanism I should be using to time drawing frames?"* - Swing `Timer` would be my first recommendation

Comment: You should also read the documentation, as `at.rotate(Math.toRadians(90), Math.toRadians(90), Math.toRadians(90));` doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've moved over to a JLayeredPane to get the effect I was looking for. I'm able to click through the top layer and drag the bottom layer. [image]

```
    LayerUI backgroundUI = new WallpaperLayerUI();
    jlayer = new JLayer<JPanel>(panel, backgroundUI);

    LayerUI controlsUI = new LayerUI();
    JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
    MigLayout layout = new MigLayout(
            "debug, insets 10, gap 10, wrap", // Layout Constraints
            "[fill,grow][fill,grow][fill,grow]", // Column constraints with default align
            "[fill,grow][fill,grow][fill,grow]");
    controlPanel.setLayout(layout);
    controlPanel.add(new JButton("here"));
    controlPanel.add(new JButton("here"));
    controlPanel.add(new JButton("here"));
    controlPanel.add(new JButton("here"));
    controlPanel.add(new JButton("here"));
    controlPanel.add(new JButton("here"));
    controlPanel.add(new JButton("here"));
    controlPanel.add(new JButton("here"));
    controlPanel.add(new JButton("here"));

    jlayer2 = new JLayer<JPanel>(controlPanel, controlsUI);

    panel.addMouseListener(this);
    panel.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    panel.addMouseWheelListener(this);

    finalPanel = new JLayeredPane();
    finalPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 310));
    //finalPanel.setLayout(null);
    jlayer.setBounds(0, 0, (808-40)/3, (608-40)/3);
    jlayer2.setBounds(0, 0, (808-80)/3, (608-80)/3);
    controlPanel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    finalPanel.add(jlayer, new Integer(0));
    finalPanel.add(jlayer2 ,new Integer(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you watch closely you'll see the buttons popping up when you hover over where they are supposed to be.

This implies you have a ZOorder problem. The ZOrder is the order in which components get painted when they are stacked on top of one another on the z-axis.

Swing paints components in the reverse order that the component is added to the panel, so the last component added gets painted first. So it sound like you have multiple panels stacked on top of one another and the last panel you added contains the buttons, but it gets painted first so all the other panel paint over it.

When the mouse moves over the button the button needs to repaint itself to show the rolloever effect of the button, so the button temporarily get painted on top until the next repaint of the parent panel when the proper ZOrder is re-established.

I don't know enough about the structure of your program, but I would question why you have a bunch of panels stacked on top of one another. All you should need is the one panel with the custom painting and then you place the buttons on this panel.

Comment: It's one panel repeated 9 times in a JFrame. There is only one JPanel in each area of the MIGLayout that I add a button to and override paintComponent.

Comment: @HaskellMcRavin, You are not doing what you described or the buttons would display on the panel. There is no trick to displaying buttons on a panel. Or maybe you are not using a layout manager properly. In any case post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. And don't use a MigLayout since that is not a standard JDK class. So first get you program working with one panel with custom painting and buttons added to the panel. Then you try adding a second panel. When it stops working then you know what you just changed. We can't help because we don't know the context of your current code.

Comment: I am doing what I described. Disregard the layout because it happens in single instances. Saying not to use MIGLayout because it's not standard is laughable. This is the pertinent code which demonstrates the problem. I've reordered the buttons to be added first and it makes no difference.

Comment: @HaskellMcRavin *"This is the pertinent code which demonstrates the problem"* - But can we run it? Can we replicate it? NO, it is NOT a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - Please take the time to read and understand what is been asked

Comment: @HaskellMcRavin, `This is the pertinent code which demonstrates the problem.` - until the problem is solved, you don't know what the "pertinent" code is.  `Saying not to use MIGLayout because it's not standard is laughable.` -  I said don't use it for the purposes of your "MCVE". I don't use that library so I can't compile and test your code. You have stated the problem is custom painting and displaying buttons on the panel. So the layout manager is not relevant to the problem. Get a simple example working first so you understand the basic concept. Then use whatever layout manager you want.

Comment: I don't think you guys have read the page you're linking to. It doesn't say anything about posting a running example. These are the pertinent parts of the code as I demonstrated by changing the parts of the code I posted in the OP. Stop flaming me.

Comment: @HaskellMcRavin, The description under "Complete" is: `Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included:` - we can't reproduce the problem because we can't execute your code. The problem could be JDK version or OS version. If we can't test the code we can't verify your stated problem. You can copy/paste/compile/execute the given to you in MadProgrammer's example. We can't do that with your partial code. You asked for the help. Make an effort to give us the information we need to solve the problem.

Comment: You also missed the "minimal" description which states `Restart from scratch. Create a new program, adding in only what is needed to see the problem.` - you stated your problem was using a panel with animated painting and buttons on the panel. So that is what you need to post 1) a JFrame 2) a JPanel with custom painting 3) buttons added to the panel. This minimal example will be about 20-30 lines of code. Once you get this basic version working you add more complex code one step at a time until it stops working. This is basic debugging!

Answer (score 0):

Your primary issue is right here...

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
g2d.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);

AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(0, 0);
```

The `Graphics` context passed to your component is a shared resource, it is passed to ALL the components painted during a paint cycle, this means that when you change things like the origin point and rotation it effects ALL the component painted after it.

Instead, you should be creating a copy of the `Graphics` state before you apply your changes, this leaves the original state unchanged

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
g2d.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);

AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(0, 0);
//...
g2d.dispose();
```

You second mistake is...

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        update();
    }
}, 0, (long) Math.round(motion.getFrameTime() * 1000));
```

Swing is not thread safe, and updating the UI or the state that the UI depends on could have unexpected and difficult to diagnose results.

In this case you have two choices, either use a Swing `Timer` or a `SwingWorker` depending on your needs.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details

Another issue is `at.rotate(Math.toRadians(90), Math.toRadians(90), Math.toRadians(90));`. This simply doesn't make sense.

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#rotate(double,double,double)) states

> ```
>  public void rotate​(double theta,
>                    double anchorx,
>                    double anchory)
> ```
>
> Concatenates this transform with a transform that rotates coordinates around an anchor point. This
>   operation is equivalent to translating the coordinates so that the
>   anchor point is at the origin (S1), then rotating them about the new
>   origin (S2), and finally translating so that the intermediate origin
>   is restored to the coordinates of the original anchor point (S3). This
>   operation is equivalent to the following sequence of calls:
>
> ```
>  translate(anchorx, anchory);      // S3: final translation
>  rotate(theta);                    // S2: rotate around anchor
>  translate(-anchorx, -anchory);    // S1: translate anchor to origin   Rotating by a positive angle theta rotates points on the
> ```
>
> positive X axis toward the positive Y axis. Note also the discussion
>   of Handling 90-Degree Rotations above. 
>   Parameters: 
>   `theta` - the angle
>   of rotation measured in radians 
>   `anchorx` - the X coordinate of the
>   rotation anchor point 
>   `anchory` - the Y coordinate of the rotation
>   anchor point

What this is saying is, the second and third parameters are actually the point around which the rotation occurs.  In your case `at.rotate(Math.toRadians(90), 0, 0);` is probably what you're really after.

## Using `Graphics#create`

[image: Happy, happy, joy, joy]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private double angle;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
                add(new JButton("Here"));
            }

            Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    angle += 0.01;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            //Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);

            AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(0, 0);
            at.rotate(Math.toRadians(90), 0, 0);
            g2d.drawRect(-50, -50, 100, 100);
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.rotate(angle, 0, 0);
            g2d.drawRect(-100, -100, 200, 200);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

## Not using `Graphics#create`

[image: Boowho]

Oh where, oh where have my buttons - probably rotated 90 degrees around the centre point of the container, based on the changes you've made to the `Graphics` context, so now they are probably off screen

Comment: I have tried to create a copy of graphics and it didn't change anything. The affine transform wasn't even used, its trash code I didn't realize was still there.

Comment: @HaskellMcRavin No runnable example, no answer - we’ve reached the end of what we can do ☹️